# How to cumulative sum by time 'bin' in R - with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to create a cumulative graph [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098551/creating-a-cumulative-step-graph-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), with another caveat. The steps should be based 2 minute time intervals, whereby an interval may have multiple or even no entries.

I used rowSums to create the column for the value to be used in cumsum, 
e.g.,

```
df_so $intraverbal <- rowSums(df_so[-1] == "intraverbal")
df_so$tact <- rowSums(df_so[-1] == "tact")
df_so$mand <- rowSums(df_so[-1] == "mand")
df_so$echoic <- rowSums(df_so[-1] == "echoic")
```

The graph worked out well enough using plot:

```
plot(cumsum(df_so$intraverbal), type="s")
```

[image: A cumulative graph - not by 2 minute intervals.]

However, there are a couple ways it falls short. Ideally, the data would be tallied and labeled according to the "time bin". At the very least, the time bins should be on the x-label, but the increments aren't continuous. Hypothetically, I should be using dplyr or lapply to melt and combine them - but I'm not sure how. Perhaps, something as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019460/how-to-get-the-cumulative-sum-by-group-in-r).

It would be nice to accomplish this with ggplot, so that the varying cumsums can be on the same graph, e.g., like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098551/creating-a-cumulative-step-graph-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), or perhaps with stat_bin as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379933/plotting-cumulative-counts-in-ggplot2).

Here's a small working sample of the data:

```
df_so <- structure(list(time.bin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 124L, 124L, 124L), .Label = c("0:00:00", "0:02:00", "0:04:00","0:06:00", "0:08:00", "0:10:00", "0:12:00", "0:14:00", "0:16:00","0:18:00",
         "0:20:00", "0:22:00", "0:24:00", "0:26:00", "0:28:00","0:30:00", "0:32:00", "0:34:00", "0:36:00", "0:38:00", "0:40:00","0:42:00", "0:44:00", "0:46:00", "0:48:00", "0:50:00", "0:52:00","0:54:00", "0:56:00", "0:58:00",
         "1:00:00", "1:02:00", "1:04:00","1:06:00", "1:08:00", "1:10:00", "1:12:00", "1:14:00", "1:16:00","1:18:00", "1:20:00", "1:22:00", "1:24:00", "1:26:00", "1:28:00","1:30:00", "1:32:00", "1:34:00", "1:36:00", "1:38:00",
         "1:40:00","1:42:00", "1:44:00", "1:46:00", "1:48:00", "1:50:00", "1:52:00","1:54:00", "1:56:00", "1:58:00", "2:00:00", "2:02:00", "2:04:00","2:06:00", "2:08:00", "2:10:00", "2:12:00", "2:14:00", "2:16:00","2:18:00",
         "2:20:00", "2:22:00", "2:24:00", "2:26:00", "2:28:00","2:30:00", "2:32:00", "2:34:00", "2:36:00", "2:38:00", "2:40:00","2:42:00", "2:44:00", "2:46:00", "2:48:00", "2:50:00", "2:52:00","2:54:00", "2:56:00", "2:58:00",
         "3:00:00", "3:02:00", "3:04:00","3:06:00", "3:08:00", "3:10:00", "3:12:00", "3:14:00", "3:16:00","3:18:00", "3:20:00", "3:22:00", "3:24:00", "3:26:00", "3:28:00","3:30:00", "3:32:00", "3:34:00", "3:36:00", "3:38:00", "3:40:00","3:42:00", "3:44:00", "3:48:00", "3:50:00", "3:52:00", "3:54:00","3:56:00", "3:58:00", "4:00:00", "4:02:00", "4:04:00", "4:06:00","4:08:00"), class = "factor"),
         Primary.VB = structure(c(1L,3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "echoic","intraverbal", "mand", "tact"), class = "factor"),
         Secondary.VB = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "echoic","intraverbal", "mand", "tact"), class = "factor"),
         Tertiary.VB = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "intraverbal","mand", "tact"), class = "factor"), intraverbal = c(0, 1, 0,1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         tact = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),mand = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
         echoic = c(0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("time.bin", "Primary.VB","Secondary.VB","Tertiary.VB","intraverbal",
         "tact", "mand", "echoic"), row.names = c(1L, 2L,3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1648L, 1649L, 1650L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, just and extended comment that I'll delete. If we ignore for a second that the x axis represents the factor numbers...does it look alright?

```
tbl_df(df_so) %>% 
  group_by(time.bin) %>% 
  mutate(Csum=cumsum(intraverbal)) %>% 
  summarise(last=last(Csum)) %>% 
  mutate(tCsum=cumsum(last)) %>% 
  mutate(time.bin=as.numeric(time.bin)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(time.bin, tCsum))+
  geom_step()
```

Comment: I added a picture. It's a cumulative tally so the values should keep going up.

Comment: Looks awesome. I wasn't familiar with some of these functions (tbl_df, group_by). I think it's doing what it's supposed to with the time bins.
Since it's ggplot the x label should be straightforward(?). Bonus points for intraverbal and echoic together...

Comment: @Donnied I wouldn't be able to relabel on the fly unless I look into the documentation...but I bet there must be a more efficient way than converting to numeric and relabeling (what I did). Maybe using an ordered factor?