# Is there any r code that gives an output of a discreate line graph?

Tags: r, graph, representation

I want to represent a discrete line graph similar to this image in r code, please help me. assume any values.

[image]

Things the i have tried & the data set is here

````r
bus.stop<-c("Polic Chowk","Regional bus stand","hospital", "Alanpura", "Housing Colony", "PG College", "Ranthambore circle" , "Railway station", "Collectorate", "New Bus stand")

boarding<-c(18,9,15,3,7,1,1,0,0,0)
alighting<-c(0,3,7,5,8,1,13,8,5,4)
load<-c(18,24,38,32,29,27,23,11,4,0)

hous.oton<-data.frame("BusStop" = bus.stop, "Boarding" = boarding, "Alighting"=alighting, "Load"=load)

plot(hous.oton$BusStop,hous.oton$Boarding, type="s")
```
````

Comment: Please provide the representative dataset with whatever code you have tried. See How to make a great R reproducible example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/16532098#16532098)

Comment: you can put something together for yourself with `segments()` ... your data set doesn't look *anything* like the plot you've requested - not clear how we would get it into that format ...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to draw a stepped line graph, you could probably acquire that with package ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(hous.oton, aes(x=BusStop, y=Boarding, group=1)) + geom_step()
```

You need to specify group=1, because you only have one observation per bus stop.

For further information, please see, e.g., [Creating a cumulative step graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098551/creating-a-cumulative-step-graph-in-r) .

Comment: I wonder whether the OP needs the specific details of solid horizontal segments, dashed vertical segments?